# Disable focus on header - listview wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, header

I'm using wpf and I've listview.

Everything just works fine, but I want to disable focusing on header (when i enter header with mouse it changes color to blue).

[I mean this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOjZq.png)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the work.

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I found that the trigger wasn't necessary, just the setter.